# c# DateTime.ParseExact fractional seconds issue

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a scenario where I'm reading values from a file and converting it to `DateTime`. The problem is that in my time, sometimes I have 5 decimal places for seconds and sometimes 6. 
For eg, `19:23:30.12345` and `12:13:33.123456`. If I have to parse this, I cannot use `ss.fffff` or `ss.ffffff`. What do I do?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("12:13:33.12345")` and `DateTime.Parse("12:13:33.123456")` work-for-me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using six capital F's. According to the documentation under [The F Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#F_Specifier) heading:

> The number of "F" format specifiers
>   used with the ParseExact,
>   TryParseExact, ParseExact, or
>   TryParseExact method indicates the
>   maximum number of most significant
>   digits of the seconds fraction that
>   can be present to successfully parse
>   the string.

Comment: Lower case f for mandatory trailing zeros, upper case F for optional trailing zeros

Answer (score 0):

Why is anything special needed? Doesn't DateTime.Parse(stringFromFile) work directly, without a specifier?

Comment: DateTime.Parse also behaves differently under different cultures and allows for a wide variety of date/time formats that may be imprecise at best or completely inaccurate at worst. If the integrity of the data is important, DateTime.ParseExact should be used.

Comment: simple parse doesnt work. Here's the complete time `Mon Jan 04 19:59:57.57000 2010`